# MKMapView Crash at init

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapkit, mkmapview

[image]

```
GeoServices: -[GEOResourceManager pathForResourceWithName:fallbackBundle:fallbackNameHandler:] + 352
```

I am getting the above crash. I am using the MKMapView() initializer.

```
    class MapCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
          private let mapView  = MKMapView()
    
    
      override init(frame: CGRect) {
          super.init(frame:frame)
    
        self.mapView.mapType = .standard
        self.mapView.isScrollEnabled = false
        self.mapView.isZoomEnabled = false
        self.mapView.isPitchEnabled = false
        self.mapView.isRotateEnabled = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(self.mapView)
    
    
      }


      override final func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

          self.mapView.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 240, height: 240)
      }

    }
```

Comment: Could you actually show us the _code_ that crashes, in context?

Comment: Orignal Post updated.

Comment: I don’t know if it’s the issue here, but you really don’t want a map view for every cell. It’s a very “expensive” view object. You should use [map snapshots](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapsnapshotter). Try temporarily returning only one cell and see if that works. If it does, but multiple cells doesn’t, the problem is likely having too many map views.

Comment: There is only one of these cells.  One Map. One MKMapView.

Comment: I would suggest that saying `MKMapView()` might itself be wrong. Try giving it a frame, so that it has a size like 100x100, and see if that makes a diff. I could be off base but hey, can't hurt to give it a try.

Comment: @Rob good idea! I will switch to MKMapSnapShotter. Seems like the better way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

I think the most likely reason for the crash is that your application is referencing a resource which is not being copied into the application bundle as part of the build process.  Can you place a debug statement to show the URL being referenced in `GEOResourceManager` and check the built IPA file for what files are delivered (assuming it is a file URL being used in the `GEOResourceManager`).

Comment: It's unlikely to be bitcode, but it could be a resource that is target or device specific in some way. Add the debugging, and also provide the full .crash file and it might help.  If the debugging tells you the problem asset, take a screen shot of its properties from the asset catalog right hand pane.